# How to test a jquery and javascript program?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I just developed a JS program that also uses Jquery. I need to test it programmatically which I don't know how. I'm kinda new to testing and my search results included some software testing tools like JsUnit, Selenium.

How can I test my program?

Comment: Are you asking about tools beyond the browser development tools?

Comment: No. My program code also includes Jquery, so can I use JS testing tools? My program includes some alert boxes and I don't know how to start! (Like must I develop a testing function and pass true/false values?)

Comment: try following code check alert() and  console in developer tools and debug code in source tab

Comment: A little less chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)) is appropriate.

Comment: As it stands, I think your question is too broad for Stackoverflow. You've identified a couple of tools that you can use to test JavaScript, I recommend using Google to search for them with keywords like "tutorial" and "testing JavaScript". (I will say that if you want to test things that block the UI and require user interaction (like alert) then you'll either need something that tests from outside the browser's JS engine (like Selenium) or you'll have to mock alert.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Check Jquery and JavaScript result using alert() and console.log() method.
2.) Debug  using developer Tools  get from right click and select Inspect Element in browser

Try this code

```
   </head>
   <body>
  <input type="button" value="check" onclick="checkvaild()">         


       <script >

         function checkvaild()
         {
          alert("check");
         console.log("check");
         }
      </script>
   </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Adding to Kishan's Answer, to obtain developer tools in browser Just **Right click on your browser-> Inspect Element**

Comment: I get that! But the function checkValid() above, was developed by the tester himself, Isn't it? Is there a tool that would create this function and all that the tester has to do is to pass the testing values?

Comment: Those are useful techniques for *debugging* but far, far too manual for *testing*.